# Why pandas read csv returns raw data instead of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

[image]I am trying to read the Advertising.csv in pandas.  The output I get is raw data shrunk into one column with commas separating the values:

```
,TV,radio,newspaper,sales
0   1,230.1,37.8,69.2,22.1
1   2,44.5,39.3,45.1,10.4
2   3,17.2,45.9,69.3,9.3
3   4,151.5,41.3,58.5,18.5
4   5,180.8,10.8,58.4,12.9
```

I tried different parameters but had no luck.

`df = pd.read_csv(file_path, "Advertising.csv")`

I appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: try `df = pd.read_csv(file_path)` .  It looks like it is taking your second positional parameter as the sep string.

Comment: That was the correct answer. Thanks a bunch for your speedy help @jch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
df = pd.read_csv(file_path , sep=',')
```

Comment: file_path is the full path . it is printed out in the question.